# Variable is used uninitialized in this function -- how to fix?

Tags: c, variables, tree, binary-tree

I have a variable-related problem in c:

I am trying to implement a binary tree using a recursive function. But there is some problem in the variable `choice`.

I tried making the variable global, and also using `static int`, but still the error presists:

```
'choice' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized][text]
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
};

int choice;
struct node *create()
{
   
    printf("do you want to create a node\n 1 yes \n 2 no \n  ");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if (choice == 2)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp;
        temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("enter the data ");
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);
        temp->left = create();
        temp->right = create();
        return temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    root = create();
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: You should be able to make `choice` an ordinary function-local variable.  The call to `scanf` should normally set it, but if the call fails, it could be unset.  You should check the return value from `scanf` to make sure it's 1.  If it isn't, then `choice` will be unset.

Comment: The variable `choice` is defined outside a function, so it will have an initial value, so I don't know why the C compiler is warning about an unitialized object here. `int choice;` at file scope is a *tentative definition* of `choice`. Since there is no *external definition* of the variable, it will be automatically initialized to 0.

Comment: You need `#include <stdlib.h>` to fix the implicit definition of `malloc()`.

Comment: Can you confirm that the code in the question *exactly matches* the code you are compiling, particularly regarding any declarations of the variable `choice`?

Comment: @laveesh sanadhya, The posted code does not incur that error.  1) Post true code and 2) post more info about compiler options used.

Comment: Tip: code simplification: `struct node *temp; temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));` --> `struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof temp[0]);`.

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code with **choice variable** inside and outside the function and got no errors , even i printed the values which works fine .

Thus i think the problem is compiler related , so i changed some in your code
**here is mine :**

This is **a function to initialize a node**

```
struct node *initNode(struct node *root)
{
    int number;
    printf("enter the data ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->data = number;
    root->left = NULL;
    root->right = NULL;
    return root;
}
```

Then this is **the print function** that i used

```
void printData(struct node *root){
    if(root != NULL){
        printf("%d => ",root->data); // print the value inside root node 
        printData(root->left); // call the function with root->left as the root itself
        printData(root->right);// call the function with root->right as the root itself
    }
}
```

Then **inside the create funtion** i just changed the else statement as shown below

```
  else
    {
        struct node *root;
        root = initNode(root); // to set the data inside the node 
        root->left = create();
        root->right = create();
        return root;
    }
```

And finally in **the main function**

```
int main()
{
    struct node *root;
    root = create();
    printData(root);
}
```

I hope that this helped you.

NOTE: you could use **typedef struct** instead of **struct** like this :

```
typedef struct node 
{// it was struct node
    int data;
    struct node *left, *right;
} node; // add this line so your struct will be called with it

//example of struct malloc 
(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
//example of typedef struct malloc
(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

this is just my way you could do what you want .